# Struggling with intuition about this probability question. Symmetry argument of two balls drawn from an urn.

Tags: probability, intuition, polya-urn-model

So the question is as follows:

> An urn contains m red balls and n blue balls. Two balls are drawn uniformly at random
> from the urn, without replacement.

> (a) What is the probability that the first ball drawn is red?

> (b) What is the probability that the second ball drawn is red?*

The answer to a) quite clearly works out to be $\frac{m}{(m+n)}$, but the answer to b turns out to be the same, and my tutor said this is intuitive by a symmetry argument.

i.e. that $P(A_1)$ = $P(A_2)$ where $A_i$ is the event that a red ball is drawn on the ith turn. However I am struggling to see how this is evident, can anyone explain this?

Comment: Each ball has the same probability to turn up as the second one.

Comment: You can "call" the first ball "the second" and the second ball "the first". Think of drawing two balls from the urn, then you name one of them the first and the other the second.

Comment: @trancelocation sorry? That's not very clear I don't see how that works.

Comment: @NeatMath Well the first could be blue or red though, as could the second?

Comment: Maybe you can better grasp it when you imagine a well shuffled deck of cards and instead of the card on top you are now always interested in the second card from above. Would this change the probability of a specific card to be drawn?

Comment: Yes, that's how symmetry works @PeterWilson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part **(b)** doesn't give any information about the first ball, it is just asking for the probability that the second ball in the line is red.

Now red balls (or those of any other color!) **don't have any preference for positions in the line**, hence if you randomly pick up **any** ball from the line, its probability of being red will be the same.

Comment: thank you this is more what I was looking for I see how it works.

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 2):

The secon ball probability is$\frac{m}{m+n}\frac{m-1}{m+n-1}+\frac{n}{n+m}\frac{m}{m+n-1}=\frac{m}{n+m}$ This is the same as the first, which, by symmetry, is what it should be.

Comment: yep I know how to work it out I was just asking about the intuition as to why there is this symmetry property but I have sorted that out now.

Answer (score 0):

The second probability is

$$\frac{m-1}{m+n-1},$$

which is not the same as the first, so there's nothing to be worried about.

Comment: sorry that isn't right, the second probability is $\frac{m}{(m+n)}$. You can work it out using the law of total probability then cancelling down the fraction. You've worked out the probability the second ball is red given that the first is, but the second probability asks for the probability that the second ball is red with no information about the first.

Comment: @PeterWilson This is only the case if the selection of the second ball is independent of the first selection, and I simply don't see how that can be the case since you didn't replace the first ball.

Comment: the law of total probability does not require independence of events, hence why it involves the probability of one event given another event.